# Column update not being commited in sqlalchemy (sqlalchemy-utils)

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I have a `User` model and there is a password columns(`PasswordType`), amongst many other columns. When I try to do this

```
user = # get some user with some query
print(user.password)
# there is a password

user.password = 'something else'
db.session.is_modified(user)
# True
db.session.commit()
print(user.password)
# prints new password

user.password = None
db.session.is_modified(user)
# True
db.session.commit()
print(user.password)
# This correctly prints None

# Now the funny part,
user.password = 'something new again'
db.session.is_modified(user)
# False
db.session.commit()
print(user.password)
# Prints None again.
```

I've been at this for hours and can't figure out why this is happening.

Comment: I can't reproduce that at all.  Here's a test script:  http://paste.ofcode.org/UBBCZ36m2TMCnQpdfMVmNx  works fine in master, 0.9, 0.8.   The problem is likely with your custom PasswordType() object.

Comment: After tons of looking around etc. I found that, as you say, it was a problem with `sqlalchemy-utils` that I was using. I was required to call the `force_auto_coercion` in it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with the `PasswordType` in `SQLAlchemy-utils`.

It works when I make a call to `force_auto_coercion`.

Answer (score 0):

This may answer to your question: check this out: http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/orm/session_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.session.Session.is_modified

> Instances present in the Session.dirty collection may report False when tested with this method. This is because the object may have received change events via attribute mutation, thus placing it in Session.dirty, but ultimately the state is the same as that loaded from the database, resulting in no net change here.

You may also wanna use this as for the state management utilities (in order to know which state your instance is in).

```
>>> from sqlalchemy.orm.util import object_state
>>> print object_state(instance)
```